# How to save relationship entity correctly in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two entites in spring boot generated with jhipster first one:

Student:
@Column(name = "child_birth_date")
private LocalDate childBirthDate;

```
@Column(name = "street")
private String street;

@Column(name = "postal")
private Long postal;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "rel_student__sureler",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sureler_id")
)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "students" }, allowSetters = true)
private Set<Sureler> surelers = new HashSet<>();
```

And the Sureler entity:

```
@Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "student_status")
    private String studentStatus;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "surelers")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "surelers" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Now I have the following code to update the surelers of my studententity:

```
 @Transactional
    @PatchMapping(value = "/students/{id}", consumes = { "application/json", "application/merge-patch+json" })
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> partialUpdateStudent(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @RequestParam String sureName,
        @RequestParam String studentStatus
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to partial update Student partially : {}", id);

        // Fetch the student entity from the database
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Student with id " + id + " not found"));

        Sureler sure = surelerRepository.findByName(sureName)
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Sureler newSureler = new Sureler();
                newSureler.setName(sureName);
                return surelerRepository.save(newSureler);
            });

        student.getSurelers().add(sure);

        // Update the necessary fields
        student.getSurelers().forEach(sureler -> {
            if (sureler.getName().equals(sureName)) {
                sureler.setStudentStatus(studentStatus);
            }
        });

        // Save the updated entity using the repository
        Student updatedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);
        StudentDTO result = studentMapper.toDto(updatedStudent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

But this code produces an output like this:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "parentFirstName": "Avon",
  "parentLastName": "Buckinghamshire transmitter",
  "parentPhoneNumber": "Steel Triple-buffered Gibraltar",
  "parentEmailAdress": "microchip Ruble",
  "parentType": "Refined",
  "childFirstName": "Alperen",
  "childLastName": "Toraman",
  "childBirthDate": "2023-02-23",
  "street": "Klose Turnpike",
  "postal": 64876,
  "surelers": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": null,
      "studentStatus": null
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the surelers list has name and studentStatus as null but I do not understand why, it seems the problem is caused by the merge method of entityManager which is used in the save method (Jparepository) at least this is somehow what I came as a conclusion through debugging but I can not find a solution.

One thing to notice Sureler table can have status as null its only important that the instance which is generated while updating the student has the status set. Name exists

Answer (score 0):

Could be lazy init thing. Many to many relation is by default lazy initialized by JPA, so properties of your sureler entity are not fetched, thus remain null. Try maybe @EntityGraph annotation in your repository to rectify that, to force eager fetching. Or custom query.

Comment: Isn't this throwing a LazyInitializationException in case you're trying to access an unloaded property?

Comment: @David I will try that annotation. mbodev I did not get any excetions so far

Comment: When I try to put the @EntityGraph to my repository I am getting the following error: '@EntityGraph' not applicable to type

Comment: quick check if lazy fetching is the case:   get rid of the @EntityGraph and add   fetch = FetchType.EAGER  parameter to your ManyToMany annotations. if that helped, research why thats not a good thing to do, and read up for example https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-graph/.     If adding that parameter didnt help, your problem lies elsewhere and i was wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved I think the problem lied in the db saving the new values of sure in the table sure before adding them to the student were enough. But this brought another problme which I posted in this thread: [How to save many to many correctly in jhipster spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643434/how-to-save-many-to-many-correctly-in-jhipster-spring-boot)