# How to save many to many correctly in jhipster spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with two entities Student and Sureler (a lesson which a student has to learn) my entity of student looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "child_birth_date")
    private LocalDate childBirthDate;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "postal")
    private Long postal;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "student_sure",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sure_name", referencedColumnName = "name") }
    )
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    private Set<Sureler> listSureler = new HashSet<>();
```

And Sure like this:

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "level")
    private Long level;
```

So far I can save everything fine I am using this method to update the student with his sure (lesson) and level at which he or she finished:

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/students/{id}", consumes = { "application/json", "application/merge-patch+json" })
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> partialUpdateStudent(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @RequestParam String sureName,
        @RequestParam Long level
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        StudentDTO studentDTO = studentService.findOne(id).get();
        log.debug("REST request to partial update Student partially : {}, {}", id, studentDTO);
        if (id == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        if (!studentRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
        }

        Sureler sure = surelerRepository.findByName(sureName).get();
        sure.setLevel(level);
        SurelerDTO surelerDTO = surelerMapper.toDto(sure);
        surelerService.partialUpdate(surelerDTO);
        Sureler toSaveInStudent = surelerRepository.findByName(sureName).get();
        studentDTO.getListSureler().add(toSaveInStudent);
        Optional<StudentDTO> result = studentService.partialUpdate(studentDTO);

        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(
            result,
            HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, studentDTO.getId().toString())
        );
    }
```

But my problem is the following now. For example if I update Student_1 with lesson_1 at level 1 it saves it with no problem but if I for example do the same process for a second student but with level 2 the level of Student_1 in the same lesson is also changed to 2 I know it is caused because I am saving the level directly at the sure table but I do not know on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to change your model. Instead of having the level attribute in the table sure you need to place it in the table with relationship (student_sure). This can't be done with the default many-to-many annotation of JPA.

A solution is described here: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-many-to-many-association-with-additional-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 Entities.

```
Student
  Long id;
  List<StudentSurelerScore> scores; // OneToMany

Sureler
  Long id;
  String name;
  List<StudentSurelerScore> scores; // OneToMany

StudentSurelerScore (not a Join Table)
  Long studentId; // ManyToOne
  Long surelerId; // ManyToOne
  Long studentSurelerScore;
```

On another topic, you define id as optional only to throw an exception is it is missing:

```
@PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
```

then

```
    if (id == null) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
    }
```

Just make it required and give it a range:

```
@PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) @Min(...) @Max(...) final Long id,
```

I'm sure you meant

```
    if (studentDTO == null) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
    }
```

You then go to the Repository directly to check it again?

```
    if (!studentRepository.existsById(id)) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
    }
```

If it didn't exist, you shouldn't get a StudentDTO from the previous code.